# downloaded application doesn't launch in Debian 12

Tags: linux, debian, software-installation, launcher

I had tried to install package from developers' site/

```
root@debian:/home/lm/Downloads/telegram# dir
Telegram  tsetup.4.8.9.tar.xz
root@debian:/home/lm/Downloads/telegram# tar -xvf tsetup.4.8.9.tar.xz 
Telegram/
Telegram/Updater
Telegram/Telegram
root@debian:/home/lm/Downloads/telegram# mv Telegram /opt/
root@debian:/home/lm/Downloads/telegram# cd /opt/Telegram/
root@debian:/opt/Telegram# dir
Telegram  Updater
root@debian:/opt/Telegram# ./Telegram 
bash: ./Telegram: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

after unpacking i had move the files to /opt  folder and avoid it not in PATH variable, i had launch it directly from a folder.
But it gives me the error message.    Same if just call binary with PATH prompt
from other directory

```
root@debian:/# /opt/Telegram/Telegram
bash: /opt/Telegram/Telegram: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

and how can i fix it? (or where is i make improperly step?)

```bash
$> uname -r
6.1.0-9-686-pae
$> file Telegram
Telegram: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=88e4d9c055d23489bcc05f598f65f60d6fba74fe, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
```

Comment: a) I'm pretty certain you should **not** launch Telegram as root. b) what does `file Telegram` tell you, and what's the output of `uname -r`?

Comment: ```
root@debian:/# uname -r
6.1.0-9-686-pae
```

of coarse, i wouldn't work as root

Comment: And what is the result of `file Telegram`? You "wouldn't work as root", still you currently are working as root without necessity. So, hm.

Comment: i didn't understand, what are you mean by "file tell you" ?
it looks like executable like all in /usr/bin  folder

```
lm@debian:/opt/Telegram$ file -v Telegram
file-5.44
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic
```

or which options of file command i need to look?

Comment: Where did the -v come from? Can you please just run `file Telegram`?

Comment: just i don't know how to formatting works in a comment, there are 2 lines from my screen, i repeat them below. And of coarse, i can't to launch Telegram, the launch result screenshot is in main topic at the bottom.

Comment: lm@debian:/opt/Telegram$ file -v Telegram

Comment: file-5.44 magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic

Comment: Instead of adding extra information in comments, please edit your question and put the info there. It makes gathering all the info much easier and the question is then searchable.

Comment: @ant **DON'T** write `file `-v `Telegram`. Just write `file Telegram`. (Is this really so hard?)

Comment: Why are you adding `-v` to the magic command line? WE want info on the binary, not the version of `file` that you're running.

Comment: root@debian:/opt/Telegram# file Telegram 
Telegram: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=88e4d9c055d23489bcc05f598f65f60d6fba74fe, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped

Comment: just i didn't know yet that it possible write file command without options

Answer (score 2):

## What's wrong with what I do?

**Generally**, you shouldn't even go and download software manually from any website, usually. You say you have *debian linux*, so just install telegram directly, like you would any other software.

```bash
sudo apt install telegram-desktop
```

Done.

---

## What's wrong with what I downloaded?

You're trying to run a 64-bit executable for x86_64 processors:

> ```
> Telegram: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=88e4d9c055d23489bcc05f598f65f60d6fba74fe, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
> ```

on a 32-bit operating system:

> ```
> 6.1.0-9-686-pae
> ```

(The `686` is an architecture description that says "this is a moderner version of an intel i386", and the `pae` says that this is indeed a 32 bit kernel with physical address extension – something that instantly became obsolete as 64-bit processors became standard, nearly 20 years ago.)

So, that can't work: your machine cannot run 64 bit code.

- If you actually have a 64 bit computer, don't boot a 32 bit Linux.
- If you have a 32 bit x86 processor, you must have a very old computer. In that case, you downloaded something that doesn't work on your machine.

Comment: just because of i didn't want to choose image for AMD64, i had choose I686, because of i had Intel J4125 processor.

Comment: Sadly, that was wrong